# How to get user role in Power BI M Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am using Power BI `Role Level Security` (RLS). In RLS, we have roles like `Administrator`. I have direct query in Power M Query like,

```
let
    SomeVar = Record.Field(Table.First(GetSomeVar(Age)), "Column"),
    Role = HowCanIGetUserRoleHere,
    
    Source = Sql.Database("mydb.servr", "db", [Query="SELECT ..... UserRoleHere", CreateNavigationProperties=false])
in
    Source
```

How can I get the user role (who is viewing the dashboard) in above query?

Comment: You can't, because importing happens before any RLS logic. The import always imports all data first, then Power BI applies filtering logic based on what you've defined in DAX. That also notably means you cannot have user-specific SQL queries to retrieve data. If using DirectQuery to connect to a source, Power BI will apply the credentials of the user retrieving the data (so any filtering or security applied in the database itself happens), but you still won't be able to access those credentials explicitly in your M.

Comment: What you can do is use a [dynamic parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters) to pass (say) the `USERPRINCIPALNAME()` down to your query, allowing for filtering that way. You can't pass down "the" role of a UPN, as that's determined by DAX, and technically a user can belong to multiple roles (although that's not recommended). You could apply custom DAX logic to assign a specific role to each user, though you should take care that this remains consistent with any RLS you've defined.

Comment: Note: the above comment needs to be taken with a grain of salt as I've never attempted to use dynamic parameters this way. I'm not sure it wouldn't be really easy for a user to bypass your carefully crafted security by rebinding the parameter, which would be bad. :P This can probably be covered by using the DAX RLS to permit the user only specific values, but again, I've never tried this.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I am using direct query not imports. I am also using dynamic M parameter. USERPRINCIPALNAME is only return the email address not the role.

Comment: That's because, as I've said, there's no such thing as "a" role for a user. Instead a role defines the rules for which objects are accessible, which may be based on `USERPRINCIPALNAME` but there's no requirement that it is. Without additional logic that you write yourself, you can't explicitly link an account to a role. A DAX RLS role is not like a security group in other systems.